# Trouble Understanding glOrtho

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 2d

I'm new to openGL and im having trouble understanding the concept of glOrtho. for instance i have:

```
void display(void)
{
/* clear all pixels  */
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
/* draw black polygon (rectangle) with corners at * (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)
*/
glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glVertex3f (-.25,0,0.0);
  glVertex3f (.25, 0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f (.25, .25, 0.0);
  glVertex3f (-.25, .25, 0.0);
glEnd();
/* don’t wait!
* start processing buffered OpenGL routines */
glFlush (); }
```

this produces a rectangle and then this "morphs" the rectangle:

```
void init (void)
/* this function sets the initial state */ {
/* select clearing (background) color to white */
glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
/* initialize viewing values */ 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 1, 1, 0.0, -1.0,1.0);
}
```

and this pretty much makes it a square and puts in up in the top left corner. I'm not sure how it does that. Are the points transformed in the rectangle?

EDIT: 
figured it out. this was very helpful. http://elvenware.sourceforge.net/OpenGLNotes.html#Ortho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glOrtho` is used to define an orthographic projection volume:

The signature is `glOrtho(GLdouble left, GLdouble right, GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top, GLdouble near, GLdouble far);`
left and right specify the x-coordinate clipping planes, bottom and top specify the y-coordinate clipping planes, and near and far specify the distance to the z-coordinate clipping planes. Together these coordinates provide a box shaped viewing volume.

The way you have defined your volume of projection is not centered around the point 3d (0, 0, 0) but (.5, -5, 0) you should have defined your glOrtho this way instead: `glOrtho(-.5, .5, -.5, .5, -1.0, 1.0);` since you polygon is center around the point 3d (0, 0, 0). (You can also change the coordinates of your polygon to match the center of your projection volume).

Answer (score 2):

Your `glOrtho` call sets up the viewport such that the top-left is (0,0) and the bottom-right is (1,1), with a valid Z-range of (-1,1).

Now, you drew a square with a top-left of (-0.25,-0.25) to (0.25,0.25).

The `glVertex` calls do not match the comment just above them.  Either change the vertices to the values you stated, or change the `glOrtho` call:

```
glOrtho(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -1.0, 1.0 );
```